# Pass variable command line args via ant macrodef

Tags: java, ant

I have a java program `MyClass` that accepts a required argument `reqArg` and an optional argument `myOptionalArg`. And I'm trying to write ant target for same.

```
  <macrodef name="run-class">
    <attribute name="reqArg" />
    <sequential>
      <condition property="additionalArgs" value="${args}" else="">
        <isset property="args" />
      </condition>
      <java classname="MyClass" failonerror="true" fork="true" classpath="${classpath}">
        <arg line="--reqArg @{reqArg}" />
        <arg line="${additionalArgs}" />
      </java>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <!--Separate target for each value of reqArg -->
  <target name="run-class-arg1">
    <run-class reqArg="arg1"/>
  </target>
```

With above I can successfully invoke the program like this and it works:

> ant run-class-arg1 -Dargs="--myOptionalArg value"

Is there a way to adapt the target above so that caller can just do following without explicitly having to type `-Dargs="..."`.  It'll make things a bit easier for the caller and not remember the syntax.

> ant run-class-arg1 --myOptionalArg value

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to pass arbitrary arguments directly to Ant.

Instead, consider wrapping the call to Ant in a shell script or batch script.

### Test build.xml

```
<project name="ant-shell-arbitrary-args">
    <echo>${myArgs}</echo>
</project>
```

### Bash script named call-ant.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ant -DmyArgs="$*"
```

Example:

```
$ ./call-ant.sh hi there
...
 [echo] hi there
```

### Windows batch script named call-ant.bat

```
@echo off
ant -DmyArgs="%*"
```

Example:

```
C:\>call-ant.bat hi there
...
 [echo] hi there
```